# iOS respond to button click located under another view

Tags: ios

I know that what I want to do is not ideal scenario, but I'm trying to make button responsive, while it is located under another (transparent) view. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure but answer is NO because you can not click on portion of button which are under the view. But my suggestion is declare the button after the transparent view.

Comment: Yes it is what I'm currently doing, I was just curious if I can't do it other way.

Comment: Is my suggestion is helpful for you ?? then i put is as a answer ?

Comment: Well, no because it is not solution to the problem, it does the job, but button is not under transparent view, but above :)

Comment: ok. but enduser can not recognize that button is on transparent view,, well might be there is not any way thanks :) all d best :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
[myTransparentView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

This should let the touch pass through your transparent view and get to your `UIButton`

Comment: I just tried it on my own transparent view and it did work. There must be something else you are doing wrong

Comment: In that case it is a bad idea to place a button below it and expect it to be responsive, since you have to select cells and scroll the collection view, so you shouldn't set the `userInteractionEnabled` flag to `NO`